can't find the libraries meta_lib and meta_log in pypi
I was trying to use a legacy script from a qualcomm flashing package (Packaged for QFIL)
examining the script I found that it is:

Python 2.7.18 (I'm have little or no experience with it.
It makes imports - almost all of which succed before stopping here:
import meta_lib as lb
import meta_log as lg

what I've done so far:
1)installed python 2.7.18 and created a virtual environment and activated it.
2) tried looking up the packages using pip(from environment) - failed.
3) tried looking up forums. only found one hit for meta_log (only) and that too on stackexchange. Didn't answer my question though.
4) I also tried conda. Didn't find these packages there too.
I tried looking up the PyPi and googling for these packages.
I searched GitHub and finally StackExchange.

https://github.com/KortanZ/linux/tree/master/ql-ol-sdk/ql-ol-extsdk/tools/partition_make/common/build/lib

Thanks friend. This is what I wanted! I wish you had posted this as an answer. You not just gave me the entire SDK, but also pointed out the specific scripts. ... I had given up but needed it again today so I returned to thank you.

I don't thank just a link is good for an answer. I'm glad I was helpful, that's enough. Good luck!

could you please provide more details on what chipset and build details you are using. Thank you.

two devices with:
Qualcomm MSM8905 Snapdragon 205
Qualcomm MSM8939v2 Snapdragon 616
